# JaxB unmarshalling a strange XML with duplicate tags

Tags: java, parsing, jaxb

Have a really strange XML coming from a REST service that I cannot change.

```xml
<Response>
<ip-addresses>
   <ip-addresses>ip1</ip-addresses>
   <ip-addresses>ip2</ip-addresses>
</ip-addresses>
</Response>
```

Obviously this is an error, the inner tag should be `<ip-address>` and not `<ip-addresses>`. But there is nothing I can do about it, I just need to grab it and parse it. Is there anyway Jaxb can help in this strange situation?

I coded a model class: `IpAddress.java` with just 1 String inside:

```java
public class IPAddress {

    public IPAddress() {
    }

    public IPAddress(String ipAddress) {
        super();
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    private String ipAddress = null;

    @XmlElement(name = "ip-address")
    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }
}
```

Also have a response class like this:

```java
public class Response {
    public Response() {
    }

    public Response(List<IPAddress> ipAddress){
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress; 
    }
    private List<IPAddress> ipAddress = null;

    @XmlElement(name = "ip-address")
    public List<IPAddress> getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(List<IPAddress> ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }
}
```

When I run it, strangely the code stops (in debug) inside the setter method of the `IpAddress` class and reads the values (ip1, ip2). And next the setter of the Response class is called but the value to be set (`List<IPAddress> ipAddress`) is null.

Any ideas on how to code this to have the list of IPs considering the XML cannot be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name to @XmlElement(name = "ip-addresses")

You can also make a pojo of ip-addresses and can access the tag through it

```
@XmlRootElement("ip-addresses")
class Ip_Addresses{
String ip_address

@XmlElement("ip-addresses")
public String getIp_Address(){
return ip_addresses
}
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answering.. if I change the name to "ip-addresses" in the java code I don't think the XML results will match anymore. As mentioned I do not have control over the XML result, so I cannot change the XML content, just Java side.

Comment: Maybe you could try because I faced the same issue and it got resolved by this solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this.
It uses the [`@XmlElementWrapper` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html).
Furthermore, you don't need the `IPAddress` class,
but instead can use `String` directly.

Then your `Response` class will look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {
    public Response() {
    }

    public Response(List<String> ipAddresses){
        this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses; 
    }

    private List<String> ipAddresses = null;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ip-addresses")
    @XmlElement(name = "ip-addresses")
    public List<String> getIpAddresses() {
        return ipAddresses;
    }

    public void setIpAddresses(List<String> ipAddresses) {
        this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses;
    }
}
```